# Error while running bundle install in CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

I am getting the following error while running bundle install. I am getting this error while installing i18n gem. I am getting this error in Cent OS machine only.I didn't get this error in Windows machine.

```
[root@centos5_9 IDEA]# bundle install
JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
System.java:-2:in `arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        from DefaultResolver.java:111:in `makeTime'
        from DefaultResolver.java:277:in `create'
        from DefaultResolver.java:317:in `handleScalar'
        from DefaultResolver.java:435:in `orgHandler'
        from DefaultResolver.java:455:in `node_import'
        from org/yecht/ruby/DefaultResolver$s_method_1_0$RUBYINVOKER$node_import.gen:65535:in `call'
        from CachingCallSite.java:146:in `call'
        from RubyLoadHandler.java:40:in `handle'
        from Parser.java:300:in `addNode'
        from DefaultYAMLParser.java:676:in `yyparse'
        from Parser.java:290:in `yechtparse'
        from Parser.java:284:in `parse'
```

My gem file contains following code.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem "xml-simple", "=1.0.12"
gem "fastercsv", "=1.5.3"
gem "hpricot", "=0.8.2"
gem "newrelic_rpm", "=3.1.1"
gem "mime-types", "=1.16"
gem "writeexcel", "=0.6.4"
gem "i18n"
#gem "warbler","=1.3.0"
gem "rmagick4j","=0.3.7"
gem "starling","=0.10.1"
gem "jruby-memcache-client","=1.7.0"
gem "tzinfo","=0.3.29"
gem "jruby-jars","=1.5.6"
gem "jruby-rack","=1.0.5"
gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter","=1.2.9"
gem "activeresource","=3.2.13"
gem "activesupport","=3.2.13"
gem "bouncy-castle-java","=1.5.0147"
gem "bundler","=1.3.5"
gem "columnize","=0.3.2"
gem "eventmachine","=0.12.10"
gem "jdbc-mysql"
gem "jruby-openssl","=0.8.8"
gem "jruby-prof","=0.1.0"
gem "memcache-client","=1.8.5"
gem "rack","=1.4.5"
gem "rake","=0.8.7"
gem "rspec","=1.3.0"
# gem "ruby-debug-base","=0.10.3.2"
gem "rubyzip","=0.9.4"
gem "sources","=0.0.1"
gem "mogli","=0.0.25"
gem "facebooker2","=0.0.8"
gem "json","=1.5.1"
gem "multi_json","=1.0.3"
gem "net-ldap", "=0.2.2"
gem "multi_xml","=0.4.1"
gem "httparty","=0.8.1"
gem 'exception_notification', :require => 'exception_notifier'
gem 'safe_attributes'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "daemons"
gem 'jruby-rack-worker', :platform => :jruby, :require => nil
#gem "ffi", "~> 1.9.0"
#gem 'spoon'
gem "resque"
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyrhino'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

platforms :jruby do
 # gem "ruby-debug", "= 0.10.3"

  # This is needed by now to let tests work on JRuby
  # TODO: When the JRuby guys merge jruby-openssl in
  # jruby this will be removed
  #gem "jruby-openssl"

  group :db do
    gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "=1.2.9"
  end
end
```

I am using rails 3.2.13.Please help us on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Initially reinstall the bundler at root or set up the ruby and rails environment:-

```
$ gem install bundler / brew gem install bundler 

$ rvm use <ruby/jruby version>@<rails_version>  if you are using rvm

Now go in your application directory and then run 

$ bundle install
$ bundle update ( to get the latest version gem )
```

and you can try https://rubygems.org        # some time it will work

Comment: I have tried with gem install bundler. This time also I am getting same error.